# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name in jpa

Tags: jpa, native

I'm trying to perform a custom query (`SELECT URI AS NUMBER_URI FROM TSRECORD`) in JPA and I'm getting this error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Could you please help me to resolve this error?

SpringBootApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class RecordDisposal1Application 
 {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
{
           SpringApplication.run(RecordDisposal1Application.class, args);
        }
   }
```

Repository.java:

```
  @org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
        public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<tsrecord, Integer> 
{
               @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT URI as NUMBER_URI FROM TSRECORD WHERE RCRECTYPEURI NOT  IN ('264','263')")
            public List<tsrecord> findAllbyPaperRecord();
               }
```

tsrecord.java:

@Entity
    @Table(name ="TSRECORD")
    public class tsrecord {

```
    public tsrecord(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name ="URI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long URI;

    @Column(name ="RECORDID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String RECORDID;

    @Column(name ="TITLE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(254 CHAR)")
    public String TITLE;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHEDULEURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCSCHEDULEURI;

    @Column(name ="RCRECTYPEURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCRECTYPEURI;

    @Column(name ="RCFILEPLANURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCFILEPLANURI;

    @Column(name ="RCSECLEVEL",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCSECLEVEL;

    @Column(name ="RCNOTES",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNOTES;

    @Column(name ="ACCESSIONNBR",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long ACCESSIONNBR;

    @Column(name ="EXTERNALID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String EXTERNALID;

    @Column(name ="PRIORITY",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(5 CHAR)")
    public String PRIORITY;

    @Column(name ="ISPART",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISPART;

    @Column(name ="ISROOT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISROOT;

    @Column(name ="ISRELATED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISRELATED;

    @Column(name ="ISPARENT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISPARENT;

    @Column(name ="ISATTACHED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String ISATTACHED;

    @Column(name ="FULLRECORDID",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String FULLRECORDID;

    @Column(name ="CONSIGNMENT",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)")
    public String CONSIGNMENT;

    @Column(name ="CURRDISP",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long CURRDISP;

    @Column(name ="RCCLASS",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCCLASS;

    @Column(name ="RCCONTAINERURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCCONTAINERURI;

    @Column(name ="RCACCESSLOC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCACCESSLOC;

    @Column(name ="RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(512 CHAR)")
    public String RCSTRUCTUREDTITLE;

    @Column(name ="REGDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String REGDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="CREATIONDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String CREATIONDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="CLOSEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String CLOSEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="RCDUEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDUEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="LASTACTIONDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String LASTACTIONDATETIME;


    @Column(name ="INACTIVEDATETIME",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String INACTIVEDATETIME;

    @Column(name ="RCFINALIZEDDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCFINALIZEDDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWDATE;

    @Column(name ="HASHOLD",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String HASHOLD;

    @Column(name ="RCDATEPUBLISHED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATEPUBLISHED;

    @Column(name ="RCACCESSISCONT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCACCESSISCONT;

    @Column(name ="RCLINKEDTOCOUNT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCLINKEDTOCOUNT;

    @Column(name ="RCRECTYPESECFILTER",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCRECTYPESECFILTER;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTOPARTURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCAUTOPARTURI;

    @Column(name ="SYSLASTUPDATED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String SYSLASTUPDATED;

    @Column(name ="RCORIGIN",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCORIGIN;

    @Column(name ="RCDATEIMPORTED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATEIMPORTED;

    @Column(name ="RCSPURL",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPURL;

    @Column(name ="RCSPGUID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPGUID;

    @Column(name ="RCSPFARMID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPFARMID;

    @Column(name ="RCSPLISTTYPE",columnDefinition ="NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPLISTTYPE;

    @Column(name ="RCSPSITECOLLID",columnDefinition ="NCHAR(32 CHAR)")
    public String RCSPSITECOLLID;

    @Column(name ="RCMEDIATYPE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCMEDIATYPE;

    @Column(name ="RCFOLDERORIGIN",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCFOLDERORIGIN;

    @Column(name ="RC1CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC1CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC2CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC2CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC3CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC3CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC4CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC4CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC5CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC5CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC6CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC6CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC7CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC7CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="RC8CAVEAT",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RC8CAVEAT;

    @Column(name ="SYSLASTUPDATEDBY",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long SYSLASTUPDATEDBY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHINACTIVECALC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCSCHINACTIVECALC;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHINACTIVE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(8 CHAR)")
    public String RCSCHINACTIVE;

    @Column(name ="RCDISPOSALKEY",columnDefinition ="CHAR(9 CHAR)")
    public String RCDISPOSALKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHDISPOSALKEY",columnDefinition ="CHAR(9 CHAR)")
    public String RCSCHDISPOSALKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCSCHDISPCALC",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCSCHDISPCALC;

    @Column(name ="RCHASLONGEVITYFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASLONGEVITYFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCHASREDACTABLEFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASREDACTABLEFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCHASOCRFMT",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCHASOCRFMT;

    @Column(name ="RCCLIENTRECORD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCCLIENTRECORD;

    @Column(name ="RCMATTERRECORD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCMATTERRECORD;

    @Column(name ="RCCONSIGNMENTURI",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCCONSIGNMENTURI;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTOCONFIDENCE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCAUTOCONFIDENCE;

    @Column(name ="RCDATESUPERSEDED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATESUPERSEDED;

    @Column(name ="RCDATERECEIVED",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCDATERECEIVED;

    @Column(name ="RCGEOGRAPHY",columnDefinition ="SDO_GEOMETRY")
    public String RCGEOGRAPHY;

    @Column(name ="RCNEEDSREVIEW",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNEEDSREVIEW;

    @Column(name ="RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION",columnDefinition ="CHAR(1 BYTE)")
    public String RCNEEDSAUTHORIZATION;

    @Column(name ="RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCAUTHORIZATIONMETHOD;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWSTATE",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCREVIEWSTATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWSTATEDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWSTATEDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCREVIEWDUEDATE",columnDefinition ="CHAR(15 BYTE)")
    public String RCREVIEWDUEDATE;

    @Column(name ="RCACLGROUPKEY",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCACLGROUPKEY;

    @Column(name ="RCACLCONTAINER",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCACLCONTAINER;

    @Column(name ="RCACLEXCLUSION",columnDefinition ="NUMBER(38,0)")
    public Long RCACLEXCLUSION;
```

/*getter and setters*/

controller.java:

```
@Controller
public class controller {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    Repository Repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Iterable<tsrecord> show() 
    {
        return Repository.findAll();

    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public  String home()
    {
        return "dashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/paper")
    public String showpaper(HttpServletRequest req) 
    {
        req.setAttribute("paper",Repository.findAllbyPaperRecord());
        return "P_records";

    }


}
```

Stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:4146)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:300)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:1361)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:793)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:718)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]

Comment: Add stacktrace.

Comment: added stacktrace.

Comment: `RCRECTYPEURI` is of type `Long`, why `'264','263'` like varchar or so?

Comment: yes RCRECTYPEURI is of type Long. i removed the single qoutes in the query, yet getting the same error.                                                                                            Modified query- @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT URI as NUMBER_URI FROM TSRECORD WHERE RCRECTYPEURI NOT  IN (264,263)")

Comment: Why don't you just look at what the column names are in your database, and compare them with the ones you're using in your query?